# Having trouble understanding JavaScript currying implementation

Tags: javascript, closures, currying

Driver code

```
const join = (a, b, c) => {
    return `${a}_${b}_${c}`
}

const curriedJoin = curry(join)
curriedJoin(1)(2)(3)
```

Implementation

```
function curry(fn) {
    return function curried(...args) {
        if (args.length >= fn.length) return fn(...args)

        return function(...nextArgs) {
            return curried(...args, ...nextArgs)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble understanding this implementation of a curried function in JavaScript, specifically the recursive case.

I think that `curried` is returning an anonymous function that expects some arguments, and wraps another call of `curried` passing the last call and current call's combined arguments.

I don't understand how on the next call of `curry`, as in `curriedJoin(2)`, the execution jumps to the wrapped function's `return curried(...args, ...nextArgs)` line. Why does the execution not run through the function line by line rather than "remembering" to call this anonymous function?

I have a vague understanding of closures and I understand that the execution context is alive after the function returns - I think this is where my confusion lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand how on the next call of curry, as in
> curriedJoin(2), the execution jumps to the wrapped function's return
> curried(...args, ...nextArgs) line. Why does the execution not run
> through the function line by line rather than "remembering" to call
> this anonymous function?

That is because only the first call, i.e. `curriedJoin(1)`, calls the `curried` function directly. Calls after this, i.e. `curriedJoin(1)(2)`, call the function returned by the `curried` function.

As far as closures are concerned, closure is just a function saving a reference to the scope in which it is created. Example, function created in global scope has a reference to the global scope; similarly, `curried` function has a reference to the local scope of `curry` function.

It is this reference to the outer scope that allows a function to look for declarations in the outer scope that are not defined in its local scope.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

If I understand correctly - the initial call calls `curried`, subsequent calls call the wrapped function which accepts new args, and then calls and returns `curried` with the last call's arguments and the current call's arguments concatenated. Then we recurse until the base case is reached. And I think the closure here is useful as we have access to the previous call's arguments from the scope of `curried`. 

Do you know of any resources/examples for similar types of problems? Not currying, but`the calling a function returned by a function` part.

Comment: This [article about closures](https://yousaf.hashnode.dev/how-closures-work-in-javascript) might help.